# How to delete images form photos in ios programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to develop an app which can delete images form photos in iOS device.I have read in so many post that i can't done from app.But i have seen an app **[Flic](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/flic-delete-manage-camera/id918263212?mt=8)** on ios which delete the apps from photos.

How it is possible in ios?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @Dheeraj - Try to use that application and see if it is deleting off the pics and also Justlike is right about the feature is not supported by iOS.

Comment: I have tested it is deleeting from photos before dleeting it is asking for persmission

Answer (score 0):

You can't because it is **not** supported by iOS. [Here's a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/index.html) to the developer documentation for the Assets Library.

> [**Update:**]

Sorry, there is a API for you to delete photo in iOS8+.
Check his for detail:

[+ deleteAssets:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAssetChangeRequest/deleteAssets:)

Comment: How flic app is doing it?

Comment: @DheerajKumar Sorry, You can do it with iOS8 and later.